# WTX MQ Adapter ReplyTO Q

Tags: ibm-mq, mq, wtx

I have a WTX map which puts a message on WMQ "Q1". There is some other application which reads the message from "Q1" and then processes the message and places the response on the queue specified in "ReplyToQ" available on MQ Header information.

I am not able to find a command parameter to add the ReplyToQ in the message WTX map is placing on "Q1".

Any thoughts?

Thanks for taking the time to look at this question and helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ReplyToQueue is sent on the message header, so you must get the message with the header (-HDR) and parse it from there on your input card.

Here's the doc about the adapter's command:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wtxdoc/v8r4m1/index.jsp

You should have a type tree on the Examples to read the message with a header.

Regards,
Bruno.